# Campo ? null não está enviando se tiver vazio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Eu tenho este campo:

```
<label asp-for="TransportadorID" class="col-md-3 control-label" style="text-align:left;"></label>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="text" asp-for="TransportadorID" onkeypress="return BuscaDados1(event);" onblur="CarregaFornecedor1(this.value);" class="form-control" name="TransportadorID" id="idtransportador" />
                </div>
```

Ele é do tipo int ? null, porém sempre ao dar o submit ele dá focus ao campo, eu já olhei e não tem nenhuma função que faça isso, o que pode estar acontecendo? Isto é no editar, no novo o campo vazio funciona normal.
Não sei o que pode esta acontecendo. Alguma ideia ?

Modelo:

```
  [Display(Name = "Transportador")]
    public int? TransportadorID { get; set; }
```

Funções:

```
function BuscaDados1(e) {
var idfornecedor = document.getElementById("idtransportador").value;
if (OnEnter(e)) {
    if (idfornecedor == "?") { abreModalFornecedor1(); return false; }
    else {
        CarregaFornecedor1(idfornecedor);
        return false;
    }
}
else {
    return true;
}
```

}

```
function CarregaFornecedor1(id) {
            var url = "/PedidoVenda/CarregaTransportador";
            var id = $("#idtransportador").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: url
                , data: { id: id }
                , type: "POST"
                , datatype: "html"
                , success: function (data) {
                    console.log('entrou carrega fornecedor 1');
                    if (data.resultado > 0) {
                        $("#nometransportador").html(data.nomeFornecedor);
                    }
                    else {
                        if (id != "?" && id != "") {
                            alert('Transportador não encontrado, tente novamente.');
                            $("#idtransportador").val("");
                            $("#nometransportador").html("");
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Function `CarregaTransportador`

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CarregaTransportador(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var item = db.Fornecedores.Include(f => f.CategoriaFornecedores).Where(r => r.Id == id && r.CategoriaFornecedores.Transportador == true).Single();
            return Json(new
            {
                nomeFornecedor = item.Nome,
                ruaFornecedor = item.Rua,
                nFornecedor = item.Numero,
                bairroFornecedor = item.Bairro,
                cidadeFornecedor = item.Cidade,
                Resultado = item.Id
            });

        }
        catch { return Json(new { Resultado = 0 }); }
    }
```

Comment: tem como adicionar o modelo, e as funções js?

Comment: @Barbetta adicionei.

Comment: Você espera um NULL ou um if (idfornecedor == "?")  ... "?"

Comment: o ? abre um modal para pesquisa. e o vazio, é porque pode ser vazio.

Comment: quando você faz o `idfornecedor == "?"` na vdd ele espera que dentro do input tenha o texto "?".

Comment: Sim , ele espera que tenha o '?' pois só com o ? e enter, ele abre o modal.

Comment: @Barbetta porque o type do input é text, então ele aceita o ?

Comment: aaah sim, entendi rsrs, ele chega a entrar no `CarregaFornecedor1`? se sim, que valor o campo `var id` está recebendo?

Comment: @Barbetta ele entra sim no `CarregaFornecedor1, o campo `id` está recebendo, ele está recebendo vazio.

Comment: tem o código do controller /PedidoVenda/CarregaTransportador? pode adiciona-lo, por favor

Comment: @Barbetta adicionado.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85661/discussion-between-barbetta-and-marianac-costa).

Comment: @Barbetta consegui resolver incluindo o required direto na viewmodel, compilando e logo em seguida retirando o required.

Comment: @marianac_costa que doido kkkkkk, mas que bom que resolveu ;)